# For which $x\in\mathbb{R}^{1,n}$ do we have $(x_0y_0-\sum_i x_iy_i)^2\geq (x_0^2-\sum_ix_i^2)(y_0^2-\sum_i y_i^2)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^{1,n}$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> For what $x_0,\cdots,x_n$, we have $(x_0y_0-\sum_i x_iy_i)^2\geq (x_0^2-\sum_ix_i^2)(y_0^2-\sum_i y_i^2), \forall\ y_0,\cdots,y_n\in\Bbb R$.

It sounds as the reverse Schwarz inequality in Minkowski space. But what is the proof.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you give some more hints? I just know it looks like, but not familiar with Minkowski space.

Comment: Since $\langle x,y\rangle^2-\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle$ appears in the discriminant proof of the usual Cauchy-Schwarz, just look at what happens when you move to Minkowski space ($(+-\dots-)$ signature):  $Q(x+\lambda y)=\langle x+\lambda y,x+\lambda y\rangle$ has discriminant $4(\langle x,y\rangle^2-\langle x,x\rangle\langle y,y\rangle)$ and the problem wants the discriminant to be nonpositive for all $y$, i.e., $Q(x+\lambda y)=0$ to actually have solution $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $y$.  Can you see why for $n\geq 2$ this means $x$ is null?